# Horizontal scroll on the revisions page when the post contains long code sections

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, revision-history

The revisions page for [Was the { Levels:n } beacon tag removed/altered in Minecraft Java 1.14?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/350618/revisions), seems to have a rendering bug when it comes to displaying code.

Instead of constraining the code section to a specific width, it is allowed to fill horizontally, introducing a horizontal scrollbar to the page, and throwing the layout out of whack:

[image: horizontal scrolling as a result of the long code section]

It's worth pointing out that on the second revision, if you select 'side by side', the code section is constrained to it's own box correctly, making me think this is an issue with the 'Inline' rendering/view specifically:

[image: side by side revision comparison rendering correctly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This has been fixed:

[image: Code block no longer affecting horizontal scroll]

[This Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361318/179041) covers the bug in more detail.